# Optimizing a Select with Subquery that is loading VERY slow

Tags: mysql

I have a SELECT that is a little bit tricky, as I try to display data that has to be calculated on the fly.

The data is logged from a SmartHome system and displayed in the visualization solution Grafana.
So I have to handle all of this in MySQL and can't really edit the data or the frontend to do some of this work.

The diagram should show the average temperature per day for a time range that can be selected in the UI.
The data in MySQL is a table like that:

```
   DEVICE    |       READING       |       VALUE       |       TIMESTAMP
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Thermometer |     temperature     |        20.0       |  2107.10.12 00:12:59
 Thermometer |     temperature     |        20.2       |  2107.10.12 00:24:12
                                  ...
```

The Request first creates a virtual table (that is not in the database) with timestamps for every full hours for about 10 years.
This is running very quick and doesn't seem to be a reason for my slow fetches

After that I strip down the virtual table to values only within the visible time range in my diagram. 
On all of these full-hour-timestamps I have to run a sub-select to get the last temperature value that was logged before the full hour.

This values are then grouped by day and the average is calculated.
That way I get the average over 24 values for each full hour from 00:00 to 23:00.
Based on different wether sites, this is how the official average temperature is normally calculated.

Here is the Select Statement:

```
SELECT 
    filtered.hour as time, 
    AVG((SELECT VALUE
        FROM history
        WHERE READING="temperature" AND DEVICE="Thermometer" AND TIMESTAMP <= filtered.hour
        ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )) as value
FROM (
    SELECT calculated.hour as hour FROM (
            SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(DATE($__timeTo()), INTERVAL 10 YEAR), INTERVAL t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i HOUR) as hour 
            FROM (SELECT 0 as i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
                     (SELECT 0 as i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
                     (SELECT 0 as i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
                     (SELECT 0 as i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
                     (SELECT 0 as i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
    ) calculated
    WHERE calculated.hour >=  $__timeFrom() AND calculated.hour <= $__timeTo()
) filtered  
GROUP BY DATE(filtered.hour)
```

For a timespan of a week it already takes about 5-10 seconds for the diagram to show up. For a month you're close to half a minute.
All my other (simple fetches without calculations) diagrams are loading in about or less than a second.

As I'm a completely MySQL noob and just started to build some SELECTs for my smart home, I don't really know how this can be improved.

Any ideas from the pros? :)

Comment: this is definitely not the answer, but maybe you should use some specific time series database? Graphite https://graphiteapp.org/ has a bunch of statistics functions, Influxdb (https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/influxdb/) has SQL like syntax, also we have prometheus and so on. Great plus of such solution - it designed for dealing with metrics, it much faster when querying large periods of time than mysql

Comment: Does it have to be 24 measurements a day, or can it be more?

Comment: @PeterM I don't think the amount of measurements isn't that imporant. I think anything from 6 upwards should give a good result, that doesn't vary too much from the official calculations.

The bigger problem is, that they have to be equal intervals over the day. Otherwise you're maybe weighting night or day too much, which will provide a false result.

That is the reason why I created the "virtual table" with full-hour timestamps

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm overseeing something really obvious and it doesn't really matter on how many results the average per day is calculated you could really simplify your query and get rid of the subquery's. This should also give you a boost in speed.

```
SELECT DATE(`TIMESTAMP`) AS `date`, AVG(`VALUE`) AS `value` FROM `history` WHERE `READING`='temperature' AND `DEVICE`='Thermometer' AND DATE(`TIMESTAMP`) BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

Just replace `date1` & `date2` with the values you want, for example `2017-10-15`.

Comment: This is basically what I did as first try, but it misses at least a grouping by day I guess.
Otherwise I will get back 1 value for the whole time range instead of a table with values for each day, correct? But the main problem is, that it doesn't determinate values that are evenly distributed over the day. So if I have more temperature-changes that get logged at night than at day, I will get a average temperature that is too low.

Comment: The result should be an average for each single day between the two dates. It does not take into account of the amount or interval in the measurements. Are the measurements not logged on a set interval?

Comment: no, sadly they are logged when a change is detected. :-/
That's the whole reason for the creation of the hourly timestamps and then searching for the last logged value before.

So I'm afraid there isn't really a faster way that calculates the correct value..

Comment: I see but you are certain to get temperatures every hour?

Comment: No, if the temperature stays the same for mote than an hour, the thermometer won't report a new value to the database.
That is the reason why I create a virtual timestamp for each hour in my code above, and then look back in time for the last value that was logged. No matter if this was 5min, 1h, or 3h ago: It's still the current temperature (otherwise a newer value would have been logged).
So the code in my question is perfect working, it's just very slow. ;)

I guess I have to live with it.
It's not a diagram that look at very often, so I set it to hidden at loading time of the page now